# Correct spelling of Polish surname Czizyk or Czisik?

Tags: surnames, poland

Looking for correct spelling of my grandparants who are from Poland.  Came over to America via Ellis Island in 1913.  Immigration papers reflect: Grandfathers name: Stanislaw Czizyk or Czisik Arrived 1/19 or 1/15/1913  Born: 5/23/1885 Kurpiecz/Kurpiesc, Poland.  His wife, Julia, found 2 surnames for her: Zajaczkowska and Ziamakucka Born: 3/19/1895 Czernawta, Russia. UPDATE: New surname from surviving source: Julia Zinkowski.  Growing up, my father said she was from Bialystok) and grandpa was from Warsaw. He passed away years ago, so no living relative to ask further.
They were married 6/23/1911 in Kurpiecz, Poland.  Again, this is what US records reflect.  I am at a loss for finding my heritage in Poland. Thoughts are to start with the correct spelling, then with having birth dates I could possibly find relatives.

Comment: The duplicate has answers to a very similar question that offer some strategies.

Comment: I've updated links in the "already answered" question - they were out of date. As a Polish speaker, your surname most likely was Czyżyk - like the bird, Siskin (or Goldfinch). Over 600 people with this surname live in Poland today.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE.  I have removed the reference in the title to names being changed at Ellis Island.  Passenger lists were created in the departure ports. There is no evidence that immigration officials changed the names of immigrants at Ellis Island. See the articles listed in this answer for more information. https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/4067/1006

Comment: Have you been able to find Polish records to build a list of all those married on or about 23 Jun 1911 in Kurpiecz?  Perhaps one couple will have names something like those you are looking for.

Comment: If you could steer me in the direction of where to search polish records I will research.  I've already looked via ancestry.com/familysearch/familytree/geni/my heritage and found nothing.  Appreciate any sites that would assist me in my search.